# Canonical form of cubic curves over general fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, fields

Given a field of characteristic not 2 or 3 containing a primitive third root of unity, is it true that every nonsingular cubic curve, i.e. a curve defined by one homogeneous form of degree 3 in 3 variables, equivalent (up to a linear change of variables) to something of the form $X^3+b Y^3+c Z^3=d X Y Z$?
If not then what is the necessary and sufficient condition for the cubic curve to be equivalent to something of this form?
What is the canonical form for cubic curves?

Comment: There is no canonical form for cubic curves because the moduli space of cubic curves is not a scheme.

Answer (score 3):

Over the complex numbers, there are several normal forms.
A ternary cubic can be written as
$$
\lambda XYZ-(X+Y+Z)^3
$$
with a parameter $\lambda$.
This normal form is invariant under the symmetric group $S_3$ of permutations of variables.
This leads to the so-called Hesse normal form, given by
$$
X^3+Y^3+Z^3-3\mu XYZ.
$$
It has the property that the Hessian of any of its members is of the same form.

Hesse showed that the inflection points of a
ternary cubic over the rationals are defined over a solvable extension.
As a result, any ternary cubic can be brought to the Hesse normal form
over a solvable extension of the base field. More precise details can be found in the
reference: [Ternary Cubic Forms and Etale Algebras](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fperso.uclouvain.be%2Fmelanie.raczek%2FPDF%2FRTensmath.pdf&ei=imaJVNS5F4GhUqqmgrgN&usg=AFQjCNGkZHhIUmb5c3PQqiLFWL-TMonANw&bvm=bv.81456516,d.d24), by Raczek and Tignol.